# What is the real 'ArrayLike' object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Recently I'm reading the jQuery source code and the underscore source code at the same time.

I find there is a problem in the function that defined arrayLike object.

In jQuery:

```
function isArrayLike( obj ) {
    var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,
        type = jQuery.type( obj );

    if ( type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
    typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
}
```

But in underscore, the array like function seems like:

```
var isArrayLike = function(collection) {
    var length = getLength(collection);
    return typeof length == 'number' && length >= 0 && length <= MAX_ARRAY_INDEX;
};
```

which doesn't need `( length - 1 ) in obj`.

if I have an object `{ length: 5 }`.

In jQuery it is absolutly not a array like object, because it missed number '4' in its key.

But in underscore, my object is a array like object.

Ok. What is the real array like object?

Comment: I don't understand this question?

Comment: It somewhat depends on what you need the object for. But _broadly_ the Underscore approach is more correct. As you objserved `( length - 1 ) in obj` will not exactly handle a sparse array-like object well. Which may or may not be useful, depending on what you're going to do with it.